# Meteor publish ALL Users does not seem to work (or even get called?)

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have the following in server/publications.js...

```
Meteor.publish("users", function(){
  return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {profile: 1}});
});
```

... and in my iron router route...

```
Router.route('/', function() {
  this.layout('ConfLayout');
  this.render('UserList', {
    waitOn: function () {
      return Meteor.subscribe("users");
    },
    data: function () {
      return {
        users: function () {
          return Meteor.users.find();
        }
      };
    }
  });
});
```

...then in my template....

```
<template name="UserList">
  <h1>Users</h1>
  <ul>
    {{#each users}}
      <li>
        {{#linkTo route='user.show'}}
          <div>
            {{profile.lastName}}, {{profile.firstName}} 
          </div>
        {{/linkTo}}
      </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

...and it sort of works except the only user on the client is the currently logged in user. I am trying to get a list of ALL users for admins (don't worry about the for admins part for now).

What is also odd is that is I add a console.log statement to the publish function it never gets logged. However all the other publications in the same file seem to work fine. Also if I enable autopublish, then all the users show up as expected.

What an I missing here? Based on all I could find it seems like publishing specific fields should work for displaying all users in the client, but it almost seems like Meteor is ignoring any publications on Meteor.users altogether. I am using Meteor 1.1.0.3.

Any thoughts or help appreciated!

TIA

Answer (score 0):

OK... not entirely sure why, but I suspect I may have been missing a "this" somewhere or something, but if I change the route to not use a function as the 2nd param and just pass options and then leave EVERYTHING else EXACTLY the same, it works...

```
Router.route('/', {
    waitOn: function () {
      return Meteor.subscribe('users');
    },
    data: function () {
      return {
        users: function () {
          return Meteor.users.find();
        }
      };
    },
    template: 'UserList',
    layoutTemplate: 'ConfLayout'  
});
```